# Issue referencing System.Xml for external library using IXmlSerializable

Tags: c#, serialization, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I've updated to a recent version of Xamarin Studio and a class I use shared with Visual Studio is no longer working between the 2 platforms.  I've run into some compilation/runtime errors involving XML serialization. I have a library with the following class compiled in Xamarin studio:

```
[XmlRoot("dictionary")]
[Serializable]
public class SerializableDictionary<TKey, TValue>
    : Dictionary<TKey, TValue>, IXmlSerializable
{
    #region IXmlSerializable Members

    public SerializableDictionary()
    {

    }

    public System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchema GetSchema()
    {
        return null;
    }

    public void ReadXml(System.Xml.XmlReader reader)
    {
        XmlSerializer keySerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(TKey));
        XmlSerializer valueSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(TValue));

        bool wasEmpty = reader.IsEmptyElement;
        reader.Read();

        if (wasEmpty)
            return;

        while (reader.NodeType != System.Xml.XmlNodeType.EndElement)
        {
            reader.ReadStartElement("item");

            reader.ReadStartElement("key");
            TKey key = (TKey)keySerializer.Deserialize(reader);
            reader.ReadEndElement();

            reader.ReadStartElement("value");
            TValue value = (TValue)valueSerializer.Deserialize(reader);
            reader.ReadEndElement();

            this.Add(key, value);

            reader.ReadEndElement();
            reader.MoveToContent();
        }
        reader.ReadEndElement();
    }

    public void WriteXml(System.Xml.XmlWriter writer)
    {
        XmlSerializer keySerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(TKey));
        XmlSerializer valueSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(TValue));

        foreach (TKey key in this.Keys)
        {
            writer.WriteStartElement("item");

            writer.WriteStartElement("key");
            keySerializer.Serialize(writer, key);
            writer.WriteEndElement();

            writer.WriteStartElement("value");
            TValue value = this[key];
            valueSerializer.Serialize(writer, value);
            writer.WriteEndElement();

            writer.WriteEndElement();
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

I've compiled this DLL and am referencing it in a Windows project in Visual Studio like this:

```
SerializableDictionary<string, string> asdf = new SerializableDictionary<string, string>();
```

This gives the compilation error: 
"The type 'System.Xml.Serialization.IXmlSerializable' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Xml, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e'"

Of course, I do actually have a reference to System.Xml. In fact if I copy the class from Xamarin and paste it into the project on the Visual Studio side, the class works fine. There's a few variations of this error depending how I structure things, but this one seems to be the root cause.

Anyone have ideas why this library isn't working cross platform any more? Did something change with IXmlSerializable in the latest versions of Xamarin?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to share assemblies between Xamarin.iOS and your project in visual studio, you have to make sure they're built on top of the same core libs (mscorlib, ...)

I guess your Xamarin.iOS project is build on the `2.0.5.0` profile, while your other project is on `4.0.0.0`

The topic is also discussed on the [forum](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/7722/why-are-monotouch-dlls-all-still-versioned-2-1-and-2-0-5-0)

Comment: My understanding was that the dll's are backwards compatible, so I can reference < 4.0 dll's from the project (that used to work, at least). That said, I'm not sure where 2.0.5.0 comes from, there's no way to get my project to have that version number.

Answer (score 1):

> Of course, I do actually have a reference to System.Xml.

I ran into a similar issue in which I mistakenly thought that having a `using System.Xml` statement without error was (sufficiently) a reference that included the required type... especially since I did not have compile-time errors.

[image: using System.Xml]

Apparently, even if it allowed for `using System.Xml` (packaged in the default System.Xml library), it did not include the required `System.Xml.Serialization.IXmlSerializable`

Initial `System` references:

[image: Current System References]

So solution was explicitly adding a reference to the `Framework` Assembly; `System.Xml`

[image: Explicit reference to System.Xml Assembly]

Answer (score 0):

The System.XML namespace exists both in the System.XML assembly as well as System.Data (and this is the cause for the confusion)

Teemu explained this accurately : https://bytes.com/topic/asp-net/answers/645579-you-must-add-reference-assembly-system-xml

The post is as below:
Hi,

using System.Xml;

does *not* mean you'd have reference to System.Xml.dll assembly. It means
you are just importing that namespace, trying to shortcut the need to type
fully-qualified names of types residing in System.Xml namespace.

Namespaces are logical concepts, and they don't necessarily always go hand
in hand with assemblies. For example: System.Configuration namespace spans
two assemblies: System.dll and System.Configuration.dll

So, try taking the reference in VS with Add reference dialog (/right-click

### project in solution explorer)

Teemu Keiski
AspInsider, ASP.NET MVP

Answer (score 0):

From my perspective Stephane Delcroix answered this question correctly, but here's what you can do about it:

Note **if** you are in control of your external libraries **You should not use this method** You should either compile them for Xamarin target or use .net Standard libraries / PCL's.

**Only use this method as a last resort!**

But if you are NOT in control of you external libraries and still need to use them in your Xamarin app then here is what you can do:

Note these instructions are for Android but the same approach may work for iOS.

**Modify the Xamarin System.Xml.dll file so that it has the same version as the required System.Xml.dll.**

- Copy `C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\System.Xml` to a writable location. (We will call this `E:\`)
- Disassemble the System.Xml.dll:

  E:>"c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows_v7.0A\Bin\ildasm.exe" System.Xml.dll /out=e:/System.Xml.asm"
- Modify the asm

You can use this patch (as a guide):

```
--- E:\System.Xml.orig.asm
+++ E:\System.Xml.asm
@@ -127,19 +127,10 @@
   .custom instance void [mscorlib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeCompatibilityAttribute::.ctor() = ( 01 00 01 00 54 02 16 57 72 61 70 4E 6F 6E 45 78   // ....T..WrapNonEx
                                                                                                              63 65 70 74 69 6F 6E 54 68 72 6F 77 73 01 )       // ceptionThrows.
   .permissionset reqmin
-             = {class 'System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermissionAttribute, mscorlib, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e' = {property bool 'SkipVerification' = bool(true)}}
-  .publickey = (00 24 00 00 04 80 00 00 94 00 00 00 06 02 00 00   // .$..............
-                00 24 00 00 52 53 41 31 00 04 00 00 01 00 01 00   // .$..RSA1........
-                8D 56 C7 6F 9E 86 49 38 30 49 F3 83 C4 4B E0 EC   // .V.o..I80I...K..
-                20 41 81 82 2A 6C 31 CF 5E B7 EF 48 69 44 D0 32   //  A..*l1.^..HiD.2
-                18 8E A1 D3 92 07 63 71 2C CB 12 D7 5F B7 7E 98   // ......cq,..._.~.
-                11 14 9E 61 48 E5 D3 2F BA AB 37 61 1C 18 78 DD   // ...aH../..7a..x.
-                C1 9E 20 EF 13 5D 0C B2 CF F2 BF EC 3D 11 58 10   // .. ..]......=.X.
-                C3 D9 06 96 38 FE 4B E2 15 DB F7 95 86 19 20 E5   // ....8.K....... .
-                AB 6F 7D B2 E2 CE EF 13 6A C2 3D 5D D2 BF 03 17   // .o}.....j.=]....
-                00 AE C2 32 F6 C6 B1 C7 85 B4 30 5C 12 3B 37 AB ) // ...2......0\.;7.
+             = {class 'System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermissionAttribute, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' = {property bool 'SkipVerification' = bool(true)}}
+  .publickey = (00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 04 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ) 
   .hash algorithm 0x00008004
-  .ver 2:0:5:0
+  .ver 4:0:0:0
 }
 .module System.Xml.dll
 // MVID: {4AB28EE6-F5EC-49E1-A1A7-69D0920BF2EC}
@@ -149,7 +140,7 @@
 .stackreserve 0x00100000
 .subsystem 0x0003       // WINDOWS_CUI
 .corflags 0x00000001    //  ILONLY
-// Image base: 0x05580000
+// Image base: 0x05300000


 // =============== CLASS MEMBERS DECLARATION ===================
@@ -201,7 +192,7 @@
   .field public static literal string FxFileVersion = "4.0.50524.0"
   .field public static literal string EnvironmentVersion = "4.0.50524.0"
   .field public static literal string VsFileVersion = "9.0.50727.42"
-  .field private static literal string PublicKeyToken = "7cec85d7bea7798e"
+  .field private static literal string PublicKeyToken = "b77a5c561934e089"
   .field public static literal string AssemblyI18N = "I18N, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyT"
   + "oken=0738eb9f132ed756"
   .field public static literal string AssemblyMicrosoft_JScript = "Microsoft.JScript, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutra"
@@ -619213,4 +619204,4 @@
 .data D_00273E18 = bytearray (
                  20 00 09 00 0A 00 0D 00)                         //  .......
 // *********** DISASSEMBLY COMPLETE ***********************
-// WARNING: Created Win32 resource file e:/System.Xml.orig.res+// WARNING: Created Win32 resource file e:/System.Xml.res
```

This changes the 2.0.5.0 version number to 4.0.0.0 and updates the public key token. (from 7cec85d7bea7798e to b77a5c561934e089)

- Reassemble

  E:>c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\ilasm.exe /dll /output=System.Xml.dll System.Xml.asm /Resource=System.Xml.res

**Make a backup of the original System.Xml.dll first.**

- Copy the 'fixed' System.Xml back to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\`

Again **Only use this method as a last resort!**